# Using sqlcmd.exe in windows task scheduler

Tags: sql-server, windows, scheduled-tasks, sqlcmd

I want to push data from one server to another using Task Scheduler and by sqlcmd. Here is the argument i use for

```
sqlcmd.exe :- -S "Server IP,Port No\SQLSERVER" -U username -P password -d 
database -Q "exec data_export"
```

The server where I want to push uses a custom port.

Currently, I'm using data_export procedure manually. But I want to do it automatically using Task Scheduler.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then your syntax should be something like this:

```
sqlcmd -S SERVER\INSTANCE,PORT -U username -P password -d database -Q "exec data_export"
```

Have you tried this?

And one more thing, when you config this in the task scheduler, you need to write sqlcmd in the field "Program/Script" as shown in your image.
And all the rest of the command should be set in the field "Add Arguments".

Comment: There is no need to add [Salutations](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/351589/4875631), they just clutter the post.